# How can I design a webpage that will display data that takes the server a long time to generate?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, celery, message-queue

I have a django-powered website and I have a (slow) python function

```
def slow_func(arg1, arg2):
    # some magic goes here
    return result
```

In particular, say it takes 45 seconds for `slow_func` to return.

I want to present a form to the user with fields where they can enter values for `arg1` and `arg2`.  When they submit the form, I would like them to see some interim message like "server thinking really hard about how to turn arg1 and arg2 into your result" while the server chugs away at computing the output of `slow_func(arg1, arg2)`.  Then, as soon as the server has computed the result, I'd like the user to see something like "Man, that was hard...I finally finished working and the answer is (blah)"

What is the right way to set that sort of thing up? In particular, say the web server timeout I'm dealing with is significantly less than the 45 seconds it will take my server to compute the value I want...what combination of technologies do I need to set up to get this done?

It seems like there needs to be some way to kick off the task on the server side (no thoughts here), and then have the browser keep checking somewhere to see if the job is done (javascript?)...and then once it knows the job is done (javascript) it could hit the server at some newly created url to gather up the result asynchronously and display it (javacript ajax?) or maybe just redirect to a newly generated url to view the result?

I'm sure this is a solved problem, but I can't seem to get the right set of terms to google for it productively.

Finale note: it would be great if the answers given could accommodate a range of possible types for the result of `slow_func`.  I.e. some use cases might involve `slow_func` returning a `float`...other cases might involve it returning an image, etc.

Comment: [socket.io](http://socket.io/) ?

Comment: eventsource or SSE will get by your http timeout and is very simple to use, as its based itself on http

Comment: you need to perform async task. checkout celery for it and long polling to notify user once the task is completed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets is what you are looking for. Return different event for different datatype

Answer (score 4):

Your question will probably be closed because its rather general. But here's a break down how to tackle your problem, of course there's several more approaches this is just a rough sketch to get you started.

1. fire an [ajax request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to the server
2. at the server trigger a [celery task](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or subprocess and save an initialization flag in cache or db
3. return an 'OK' or message from the server immediately after the
   task was trigged so your users don't actually have to wait
4. display the message
5. keep [polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) the server in the background every x seconds (ajax) to check if the process is done, you will need some endpoint that can validate such by looking at the status of the flag you've set earlier
6. return a success or still waiting message to the user
7. display that message
8. save the result somewhere in cache or database when the process is done so that the polling script will halt once your flag status changed to done
9. don't repeat yourself